# Terminate ajax call after timeout

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, timeout, jsonp

I am executing the following ajax call.
I am testing timeout mechanism and thus suspending my server on purpose. 
The problem is that although I do receive timeout in the client after one second the call as I see it in firebug still continues.

I guess there should some way to stop the call execution but I did not find one.

```
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp: "jsoncallback",
                timeout: 1000,
                success: (function(w) {
                    ...
                    },
                error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
...    
error: function() {
    window.stop()
}
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery)

Comment: I saw this post and tried this but it did not terminate the execution of the call and the process of xhr continued.